# How to pass information (through annotation) using custom url scheme in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I was trying to pass a NSDictionary using custom url scheme. I was wondering how to use the "Annotation" part of

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

I tried searching online, but without much success.

Can anyone kindly help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `annotation` parameter is only there for use with `UIDocumentInteractionController` (the "Open with..." Interface). If you don't use that, you'd usually pass additional information as part of the URL (parameters).